# MEF .NET Core how export CompositionHost?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mef, .net-standard

I have next code:

```
var configuration = new ContainerConfiguration().WithAssemblies(filteredLibraries, conventionBuilder);
CompositionHost container = configuration.CreateContainer();
```

One of exported classes next:

```
    [Export(typeof(IClass1))]
    public class Class1 : IClass1
    {
        private readonly CompositionHost _host;
        public Class1(CompositionHost host)
        {
            _host = host;
        }
    }
```

How export this container to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the host is not exported as `CompositionHost`, but as `CompositionContext`. You are also missing the `[ImportingConstructor]` attribute.

So the code would look like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IClass1))]
public class Class1 : IClass1
{
    private readonly CompositionContext _compositionContext;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Class1(CompositionContext compositionContext)
    {
        _compositionContext = compositionContext;
    }
}
```